# How do I make control-click in Opera open new tabs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, tabs, opera, opera-10

**Update:** As of version 11.50, control-click opens the new tab in background, as desired. Yay!

---

In Opera, as opposed to all other modern browsers I know, control-click does not open a new
tab. Moreover, I couldn't find any good way to configure this behavior. The best
available option seems to be [this](http://tough-to-find.blogspot.com/2008/06/opera-ctrl-click-to-open-in-new-pagetab.html). However, it's so hacky that it won't work on HTTPS sites unless you enable user javascript there, which doesn't seem like a good idea. There also seem to be other proposed solutions, but none of them seem to work.

I'd like this because my laptop has no middle mouse-button, and I'm a creature of habit.

Do people have any ideas (for the latest version, 10.50)? I'd like ctrl-click to open a background tab, but I can do with foreground. Thank you!

Comment: In Opera, you can also use shift+click, it's the equivalent.

Comment: I am aware of this.  I want my browsers to be uniform.

Comment: Opera 11.50β has ctrl+(left)click opening a new tab/page in the background. I just couldn't see the problem until i tried it on Opera 11.11, where it doesn't work. We can hope it stays that way out of βeta.

Comment: If you found the solution, answer your own question and mark it as accepted to that others with this same issue will know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried the js hack, indeed it doesn't work by default on HTTPS. But you can turn on User JavaScript on HTTPS pages: http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/using/#securepages

Answer (score 1):

Not technically a keyboard shortcut but since you mention that you want an easy solution when you're on your laptop you should check out [this extension](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/open-in-background-with-long-press/1.0.2/). It will allow you to open a new background tab with a long left click. Doesn't sound like much but on a laptop it's a life saver.

Comment: Thank you -- I haven't tried this since Opera fixed the original problem, but this seems very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Besides some hacky way as you describe, I don't think there is a way to change Opera's behavior in this manner.

The only solutions I can think of are:

- Using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click, but that's different from other browsers, then (even though I believe it was done in first versions to use the same keyboard shortcut as IE used to open in another window, when tabs were only existing in Opera. I could be wrong, though). **Edit:** This actually opens the tab and switches to it, it's not an "open in background". Adding Ctrl allows to open in background, as [shown by mrtreb](https://superuser.com/questions/126188/how-do-i-make-control-click-in-opera-open-new-tabs/159683#159683).
- Some hacky way using [AutoHotKey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) ([example of scripts here](https://superuser.com/questions/7271/most-useful-autohotkey-scripts)) to make Ctrl behave like Shift.
- Depending on the way you use your laptop, for example without a mouse and only with a trackpad, there are some trackpads which allow you to configure pressing left and right at same time send a "middle button" event (this is what I use on my laptop)
- If you are using a mouse without middle button, you can activate gestures in Opera, and the default gesture to open a link in another tab is pressing right mouse button on the click, then going down before releasing.

Answer (score 0):

There's reportedly a hacky way of doing it via UserJS (second comment on [this page](http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/236098?t=1270123451&page=1#comment2704169)), although the user in question refers to Opera 9.5.

Comment: Yes, that's what I linked to. Unfortunately, it's so hacky that it doesn't really work on https sites.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut key for it is:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> click (equivalent to middle click) ..

Comment: Indeed, adding ctrl allows to open in background, while shift + click alone switches to the new tab. However, the OP wants strictly ctrol + click only, here.

Comment: I know; this doesn't help since my hands are used to control-click. Since I use many computers, I can't use Opera everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Worked in Ver 11.00 :

- Menu --> Settings -Preferences  (or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Advanced --> Shortcuts --> Keyboard setup - Opera Standard (become blue)
- Bottom buttons:> Duplicate - Rename - [ your chosen name ] - OK

Keyboard setup - [ your chosen name ] (becomes blue)

- Edit (the bottom one) - Find - [type] Open link

Under Browser Window find:

- "Open link in new page" and "Open link in background page"

If found then change "input context" value (click on it) to:

<kbd>EnterCtrl</kbd>
<kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

IF NOT FOUND - MAKE THEM:

bottom buttons:>

New - click on value to change - type the input context above - same for Actions
 - click OK OK

No need to restart - it is taken right away!

Comment: This didn't work for me at all - this changes the keyboard behavior, but not the mouse.